# git status for machine consumption

Tags: git

Vanilla `git status` present some problems when using it for machine consumption since it is more tailored for humans, hiding or transforming some details about the status of each file. Even using `--porcelain` or `-z` presents some issues, for instance:

- Paths are relative to the root of the git repository; problematic because git commands can only use paths relative to the current location. This is easily fixable with `git rev-parse --show-cdup`
- `R` status is actually the status of two files and is printed with a different format of the usual `XX filename`. Problematic because it adds complexity to parsing.
- A single file can have two status, which adds yet another special case to handle. This can happen when you have a file "replaced" (which entails a staged add and a staged delete), and then the original file is placed again in the workspace:

  ```
  > git status --porcelain
  R  oldFile -> newFile
  ?? oldFile
  ```

Are there any git plumbing commands, or other approaches, that can give a more cleaner access into the state of files in the workspace that have any difference with stage or head?

Comment: Does [`git ls-files`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) help?

Comment: @MagnusBäck Not exactly, but it lead me to find `git diff-index` and `git diff-files`, which seems like could be the building blocks of `git status` and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`git status`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_porcelain_format) documentation. Emphasis mine.

> The porcelain format is similar to the short format, but is guaranteed not to change in a backwards-incompatible way between Git versions or based on user configuration. This makes it ideal for parsing by scripts. The description of the short format above also describes the porcelain format, with a few exceptions:
>
> 1. The user’s color.status configuration is not respected; color will always be off.
> 2. The user’s status.relativePaths configuration is not respected; paths shown will always be relative to the repository root.
>
> **There is also an alternate `-z` format recommended for machine parsing.** In that format, the status field is the same, but some other things change. **First, the `->` is omitted from rename entries and the field order is reversed (e.g `from -> to` becomes `to from`).** Second, a NUL (ASCII 0) follows each filename, replacing space as a field separator and the terminating newline (but a space still separates the status field from the first filename). Third, filenames containing special characters are not specially formatted; no quoting or backslash-escaping is performed.

You'll obviously have to adapt your processing to handle the seperating `NUL` character correctly but besides this the output seems to be more easily accessible.

Comment: I have also played around with the `-z` option. It presents the same issues stated in the question: R status with special format, double status for single file. It is definitely better that `--porcelain` but it still masks some of the information behind more human friendly abstractions.